# SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I got the following error when I tried to insert data into oracle using Oracle SQL Developer tool.
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
*Cause:
*Action:

My Insert SQL as follows. Anyone can help me please?

```
INSERT INTO MS9.MYTAB(    
    2001_ACCOUNT_STATUS,
    2001_CDP_ACCOUNT_NO,
    2001_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    2001_LOGIN_FAIL_CNT,
    2001_MAILING_ADDRESS_ID,
    2001_MOBILE_CTY_CD,
    2001_MOBILE_NO, 
    2001_OFFICE_TEL_CTY_CD, 
    2001_OFFICE_TEL_NO,
    2001_OTP_SECURITY_CD,
    2001_REGISTER_DT, 
    2001_RESIDENT_ADDRESS_ID, 
    2001_ID,
    2001_USER_ID,
    2001_USER_ID_TYPE,
     2001_USER_ID_TYPE_OTH,
     2001_USER_NAME,
     2001_USER_TYPE,
     2001_VERIFY_STATUS,
     LAST_UPDATED_TIME,
     CREATED_TIME,
     CREATED_BY,
     LAST_UPDATED_BY,
     2001_PWD_CHANGED_DT,
     TRANSACTION_ID,
     VERSION_NO) 
VALUES( 
    'A',
    null,
    'jxxxxxso@baml.com',
    4,
    'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93',
    '65',
    '12345678',
    null,
    '23456789',
    '63ACF060850971EFE22928E62B9EAD==',
    '42684',
    'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93',
    'TD1611100003',
    'GAxxxx678',
    'P',
    null,
    'Name 1',
    'C',
    'V',
    to_date('10-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),
    to_date('10-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),
    'System',
    'Name 1',
    to_date('10-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),
    'testtransactionid111',
    9);
```

Data type of all the above date columns are DATE.
Any idea please?

Thank you in advance,
Regards,

Comment: ORA-01847 is a data type conversion error. So you a passing a value which is not a valid date to a column which is defined as a DATE. Which one is for you to figure out. You can see the table structure, we cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found 2001_Register_DT (11th) should be date, not that value '42684'.

Comment: Oh!! Yeah. Thank yo so much, lkrom.

Comment: @Cool Please set for the answer Green flag and also Vote for that (left side to the answer box), it will show that the answer is correct. Thanks ;)